# 'stipend' : How did 'a tree trunk' evolve to mean 'payment, gift'?

Tags: etymology, latin

> [stipend (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=stipend&searchmode=none)   
>       early 15c., "periodical payment; soldier's pay," from Latin stipendium "tax, impost, tribute," in military use "pay, salary," from ***stips* "alms, small payment, contribution of money, gift"** + pendere "weigh" (see [pendant](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pendant&allowed_in_frame=0)). According to Klein's sources, the first element is related to Latin ***stipes* "log, stock, trunk of a tree"** (see [stipe](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=stipe&allowed_in_frame=0)). As a verb from late 15c.

I fail to imagine how ***stipes*** evolved into ***stips***. Would someone please advise?

I heed the Etymological Fallacy. But what are some right ways of interpreting this etymology, to make it feel reasonable and intuitive?

Answer (score 1):

Once again, Varro has an explanation to propose. For what it's worth.
In [Lingua Latina Book 5, 182](http://www.loebclassics.com/view/varro-latin_language/1938/pb_LCL333.169.xml).  (Book 5 has a lot of etymologies for many words related to money).

tl;dr According to Varro, these coins of little value were commonly offered to the Gods in alms boxes (mites) called *stirps* 'trunks' (supposedly carved out of a trunk - see trunk as coffer/chest and then trunk/boot of a car).
Although this etymology seems to rely on the similarity between *stirps* and *stips*, please note that:

1. The French word for such a mite in churches is still *tronc*.
2. Stirpe in Present Day Italian still means offspring => race => pedigree
3. One of the meanings of *stips*, *stipis* is precisely that of alms.

> 182. Hoc ipsum stipendium a stipe dictum, quod aes quoque stipem dicebant: nam quod asses librae1 pondo erant, qui acceperant maiorem numerum non in arca ponebant, sed in aliqua cella stipabant, id est componebant, quo minus loci occuparet; ab stipando stipem dicere coeperunt. Stips ab στοιβή fortasse, Graeco verbo. Id apparet, quod ut tum institutum etiam nunc diis cum thesauris asses dant stipem  dicunt, et qui pecuniam alligat, stipulari et restipulari. Militis stipendia ideo, quod eam stipem pendebant; ab eo etiam Ennius scribit:
>
> `Poeni stipendia pendunt`.

Translation from Loeb 333:

> 182. This very word *stipendium* 'stipend' is said from *stips* 'coin,' because they also called an *aes* 'copper coin' a *stips*; for because the *asses* were a
>        pound each in weight, those who had received an unusual number of them did not put them in a strong-box, but *stipabant* 'packed,' that is *componebant* 'stored,' them away in some chamber, that they might take up less space; they started the use of the word *stips* from *stipare* 'to pack.' *Stips* is perhaps from the Greek word *στοιβή* heap.' This is clear, because, as was then started, so even now they speak of a *stips* when they give money to the temple treasuries for the gods, and those who make a contract about money are said to *stipulari* 'stipulate' and *restipulari* 'make counter-stipulations.' Therefore the soldier's *stipendia* 'stipends,' because they *pendebant* 'weighed' the *stips*; from this moreover Ennius writes:
>
> `The Phoenicians pay out the stipends.`

For good measure, I'm including [the French translation](http://remacle.org/bloodwolf/erudits/varron/lingua5.htm) which, I find clearer:

> 182. *Stipendium* (solde) vient de *stips*, nom qu'on donnait aussi à la monnaie de cuivre. Comme l'as pesait une livre, ceux qui en avalent reçu une grande quantité déposaient leur argent, non dans une cassette, mais dans quelque lieu convenable, où ils le rangeaient et l'entassaient, pour qu'il occupât moins de place; et de *stipare* on a fait *stips*. On pourrait voir aussi l'origine de stips dans le mot grec *στοιβή*, qui a le même sens que *stipatio*. Ce qui autorise cette étymologie, c'est qu'on appelle *stips* l'offrande d'argent que, suivant l'usage antique, on dépose dans le tronc des temples, et que *stipulari* et *restipulari* se disent de ceux qui s'engagent à payer une somme. *Stipendium* est composé de *stips* et de *pendere* (peser, payer). On lit dans Ennius :
>
> `Poeni stipendia pendunt`

Comment: I'm no kind of Latinist, but the last piece looks to like it's been tacked on to align *stipendium* with *-pendium* words having to do with 'weighing out' the sum due. I wonder if this isn't soldier slang. Roman soldiers were paid by the day, but only received the accumulation three or four times a year. It would be a good joke to refer to this "heaped up" back pay with a very legal-sounding term. ... in any case, I see nothing to associate *stipendium* with *stipes*, which seems to derive from a different root.